android - Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content / Xiaomi specific
In my Android application, some logs are written to files by date (for example, to the file 20.06.2024.txt) with the ability to collect all files in a zip archive and share through the application/send in an email. The archive file is attached to the letter without any problems on all devices, except for one of the 6 devices on which this was tested - Xiaomi. On this device, I see an error in the logs:

Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.own.vpn.provider/files/logs/VPN_logs.zip from pid=6231, uid=1000 requires the provider to be exported , or grantUriPermission()

My provider defined in manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
    package="com.own.vpn">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:name=".presentation.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/vpn"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashScreen"
        tools:targetApi="34">
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.screens.applist.view.AppListActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/protected_applications"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.VPN" />
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.screens.log.view.LogActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.VPN" />
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.screens.loglist.view.LogListActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/event_log"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.VPN" />
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.screens.settings.view.SettingsActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/settings"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.VPN" />
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.screens.main.view.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.VPN.SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".presentation.service.vpnservice.MyVpnService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.VpnService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".presentation.service.aidlapiservice.AIDLApiService"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="ExportedService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.own.vpn.REMOTE_CONNECTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>


file_provider_paths.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="files" path="/" />
</paths>


Share intent calling
private const val FILE_TYPE_TXT = "txt/*"
private const val FILE_TYPE_ZIP = "application/zip"
private const val AUTHORITY_EXTENSION = ".provider"

class DefaultShareRouter(
    private val context: Context
) : ShareRouter {

    override fun goToFileSharing(logFile: File, shareWith: ShareWith) {
        val fileUri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}$AUTHORITY_EXTENSION",
            logFile
        )

        val fileType = if (logFile.extension == LOG_FILE_EXTENSION_TXT)
            FILE_TYPE_TXT
        else
            FILE_TYPE_ZIP

        when (shareWith) {
            ShareWith.ANY_APP -> openApplicationChooser(fileUri, fileType)
            ShareWith.EMAIL -> openEmailIntent(fileUri, fileType)
        }
    }

    private fun openEmailIntent(fileUri: Uri, fileType: String) {
        // Receivers list
        val mailReceivers = arrayOf(getString(context, R.string.mail_receiver))

        val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
            // File
            setDataAndType(fileUri, fileType)
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri)

            // E-mail
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailReceivers)
            putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                getString(context, R.string.mail_subject)
            )
            putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                getString(context, R.string.mail_text)
            )
        }

        val emailApps = context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:")),
            0
        )
        val emailAppsIntents = emailApps.map { resolveInfo ->
            Intent(emailIntent).apply {
                setPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName)
            }
        }
            .distinctBy { it.`package` }
            .toMutableList()

        if (emailAppsIntents.isNotEmpty()) {
            val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
                // removeAt(0) - first intent used as default for chooser
                emailAppsIntents.removeAt(0),
                getString(context, R.string.choose_email_application)
            ).apply {
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, emailAppsIntents.toTypedArray())
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            }
            context.startActivity(chooserIntent)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                getString(context, R.string.no_email_application),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }

    private fun openApplicationChooser(fileUri: Uri, fileType: String) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
            // Attachment
            setDataAndType(fileUri, fileType)
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri)
        }

        // Applications chooser
        val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(
            intent,
            null
        ).apply { addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) }
        startActivity(context, shareIntent, null)
    }
}

UPD
First error i get when chooser is opened. When i select any app (for example, gmail) - i get another error:
Failed to find provider info for com.own.vpn.provider. But on other devices all works fine.

Error is due to the way Xiaomi handles URI permissions
Try below code :

file_provider_paths.xml:

<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="logs" path="logs/"/>
</paths>


Use this function goToFileSharing :

override fun goToFileSharing(logFile: File, shareWith: ShareWith) {
    
    val fileUri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context,
        "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}$AUTHORITY_EXTENSION", // AUTHORITY_EXTENSION = ".provider"
        logFile
    )

    val fileType = if (logFile.extension == LOG_FILE_EXTENSION_TXT)
        FILE_TYPE_TXT
    else
        FILE_TYPE_ZIP

    openApplicationChooser(fileUri, fileType)
}

private fun openApplicationChooser(fileUri: Uri, fileType: String) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
        // E-mail attachment
        setDataAndType(fileUri, fileType)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri)
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    }

    // Applications chooser
    val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(
        intent,
        null
    ).apply { addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) }
    startActivity(context, shareIntent, null)
}

Note :

Make sure MIUI optimizations are not interfering with your application's behavior.

Check applicationId: Ensure that BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID correctly reflects your package name.



with your changes it still works correctly (with share via gmail or another apps) on google pixel, samsung devices, xiaomi redmi 6, but not on Redmi Note 10...

Can you post complete AndroidManifest.xml and class associated with function goToFileSharing .

I updated the code for the question

You need to add permission Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION and Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION Check this link for more information . Also I wanted to know all the device os versions.

I alrady tried to add this flags for all Intent which was created in my code - it had no effect. Device: Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 / Android 11 / MIUI 12.5.5

Can you check this code on any other android 11 device or simulator ?

i'll try to do it now

it works fine on emulator with android 11. On android 9 xiaomi device it works corryctly too

anyway thanks for your help

@Sunbey13 You are welcome +1 to your question.
